# Inaccurate Event Value in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I have problem with event in Google Analytics. the **`Event Action`** shows inaccurate(negative) value in large amount.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Event Tracking code for `Event Action` **`(Play Done)`** :

```
ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Mziiki Song Streaming', eventAction: 'Play Done', eventLabel: song_title, eventValue: total_sec});
```

Here, `song_title` & `total_sec` is dynamic values.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked how you are determining how you compute the song_title and total_sec? The event syntax itself looks fine.

Comment: @nyuen. song_title and total_sec is getting from the title and time div i used in HTML5 audio player and it alert the value passed in it.

Comment: Maybe try to console out those values just before you send the event, and see what they are.

Comment: @nyuen, some times it will be blank..I just track by putting alert on `Play Done` event . so it's create issue ?

Comment: So there's a problem more with how you are getting those values then.

Comment: Yes, I just want to confirm that this is the reason of negative value shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen when the event value has been passed as a string instead of numeric.  Try wrapping the value in an explicit parseInt():

```
ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Mziiki Song Streaming', eventAction: 'Play Done', eventLabel: song_title, eventValue: parseInt(total_sec)});
```

Comment: Thanks MarkeD's..but I passed numeric event value

Comment: Sometimes I send it blank..that was the reason of this

Comment: When it happened to us, it was as a the string had overflowed the value.  Perhaps look to breakdown the events to see if one in particular has done this, if possible? Perhaps date breakdown, pin down a day.

Comment: I agree with you..I m not passed blank event value now and it's working fine..shows positive results